# Django Ajax - Update table after submitting form

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, html-table

Good evening,

inside my page there are two areas - one in which the form with the new data is submitted and a second one where all the entries should be displayed inside a table..

I'm still new to javascript, so I'm asking myself, wether it's possible to update the table with the new data after pressing the submit button (and without refreshing the whole page)!?

**models.py**

```
class AjaxTable(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100)])

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

**views.py**

```
def javascript_ajax_table_update(request):
    qs_table = AjaxTable.objects.all()
    form = AjaxTableForm()
    data = {}

    if request.is_ajax():
        form = AjaxTableForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['first'] = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
            data['last'] = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
            data['age'] = form.cleaned_data.get('age')
            data['status'] = 'ok'
            return JsonResponse(data)

    context = {'formset': form, 'qs_table': qs_table}
    return render(request, 'app_django_javascript/create/django_javascript_ajax_table_update.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class AjaxTableForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AjaxTable
        fields = '__all__'
```

**template.html**

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="cnt-create">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="post-form" name="post-form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="div-post-input-flex">
                        <div class="div-post-input">
                            <label>First Name</label><br>
                            {{ formset.first_name }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="div-post-input">
                            <label>Last Name</label><br>
                            {{ formset.last_name }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="div-post-input">
                            <label>Age</label><br>
                            {{ formset.age }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="div-post-input">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                            Save
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cnt-view">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <table class="table table-hover" id="ajax-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Age</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for item in qs_table %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ item.first_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ item.last_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ item.age }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
const form = document.getElementById('post-form')
const first_name = document.getElementById('id_first_name')
const last_name = document.getElementById('id_last_name')
const age = document.getElementById('id_age')

const csrf = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')
const url = ""

form.addEventListener('submit', e=>{
    e.preventDefault()

    const fd = new FormData()
    fd.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrf[0].value)
    fd.append('first_name', first_name.value)
    fd.append('last_name', last_name.value)
    fd.append('age', age.value)

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data: fd,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response)
            setTimeout(()=>{
                first_name.value = ""
                last_name.value = ""
                age.value = 0
            }, 1000)
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log(response)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    })
})
```

Comment: what does `console.log(response)` gives you ?